# i cannot get my location using network provider? but it was always enabled

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-location

```
if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManagers.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManagers != null) {
                    location = locationManagers.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();

                        Geocoder geocoder;
                        List<Address> addresses;
                        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                        address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        //                              String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                        //                              String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                    }
                }
            }
```

above was my code to get location. It was working well previously. But today i am checking suddenly it wont get any location. It was skipped at this point requestLocationUpdates().I dont know where was the actual problem... i used wifi for getting location update.i checked all the settings.

Comment: Have you change your manifest permission ?

Comment: ya i added all permissions.

Comment: did you try restarting your device?

Comment: @cosmincalistru no not yet...

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15112242/1369566

Comment: @cosmincalistru condition was showing that network was enabled.. but it wont go after this line requestLocationUpdates..

Comment: @MohitRaval i restarted no use bro.

Comment: Have you checked this above link ?

Comment: please use this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169143/android-location-listener-in-service-does-not-work-until-i-reopen-wifi-mobile-ne**

Comment: please change LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER to LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER and than check onLocationChanged(). I hope it will work.

Comment: @MohitRaval i used both gps_provider and network provider. If gps failed that time i will use network provider.