# How Geocoder is used in subclass

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-activity, google-geocoder

How Geocoder can be used in subclass what value should i use in its context. Following is my code,

parent class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.distance_foam);
    setAllAttributes();

    dataSource = new PlacesDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();

}

private void setAllAttributes() {
    backButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBackButton);

    milesEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.saveDistance);
    minsEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.saveMinutes);
    phoneEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);
    msgEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textMsg);

    storeDetailButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.storeData);

    storeDetailButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                            locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    Long.parseLong(mins),
                                    Float.parseFloat(miles),
                                    locationListener);
}
```

subclass

```
private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String title = null;
        //error 
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this);

        Places place = new Places();

        StringBuffer description = new StringBuffer();
        description.append("http://maps.google.com?q=");
        description.append(location.getLatitude());
        description.append(",");
        description.append(location.getLongitude());

        try {
            List<Address> list = geo.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

            Address add = list.get(0);
            title = add.getLocality();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "does not find the current location");
            e.printStackTrace();

            place.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            place.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
            place.setZoom(DEFAULT_ZOOM);
            place.setTitle(title);
            place.setDescription(description.toString());

            place = dataSource.updateCreate(place);

            Log.i(LOGTAG, "data is created with id: " + place.getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

by putting "this" in initialization of Geocoder it is giving me an error as obvious, i have also built constructor but it is also giving me a run time error. please tell me what should i use to done with geocoder. Thanks

Comment: You need pass context to GPSLocationListener

Comment: please tell me which context should be passed i have already passed **getApplicationContext** and other related things.

Comment: I have also pass context with constructor but application crashes at run time.

Comment: what is yout logcat?

Comment: by working with constructor the logtag tells constructor connot be passed and by getApplicationContext **onLocationChanged** method doesn't run which should be run to perform insertion in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this);
```

to this:

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: application runs but **onLocationListener** method doesn't work.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169143/android-location-listener-in-service-does-not-work-until-i-reopen-wifi-mobile-ne)

Comment: If i am not using Geocoder it is working absolutely correct where as problem stands with Geocoder

Comment: getApplicationContext runs. i have done a foolish mistake, i haven't close the catch exception bracket.