# do I need to enable gps when using NETWORK_PROVIDER

Tags: android, gps, location

I've written an android application that needs the user location, it was working fine when I used gps provider, but I don't want to use GPS because it uses a lot of battery, here is my code

```
LocationManager locaionManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,5*1000,0, new MyLocaionListener());
Location loco = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
Log.d("enabled=" ,"" + locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
```

This code returns a `null` Location Object, and the logCat shows `enabled=false` when the location service is disabled **although I'm using NETWORK_PROVIDER** But when I enable the location service from the phone settings I get `enabled=true` and I get my current location.
So my question is:
does network provider also uses the phone GPS? and how do GPS and NETWORK providers internally works.

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594932/network-provider-not-providing-updated-locations

Comment: Have you considered using the FusedLocationProvider available in Google Play Services? It should allow you the more effectively balance accuracy and battery use without significant logic on your end.

Comment: @NasaGeek does it need to enable gps??