# Network LocationListener in galaxy sIII jb 4.1

Tags: android, networking, location

In my Service I track my location every X minutes.
I Try with

```
LocationManager lm=(LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);

criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);        
String provider=lm.getBestProvider( criteria, true );
if (provider!=null){

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider,5000,1,locationListenerNetwork);
}
```

Using Network location, and if it's not avaible i try with gps location.

The problem is that when provider is avaible, i try to ask for a location with

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider,5000,0,locationListenerNetwork);
```

where LocationListenerNetwork is my LocationListener, but nothing happends,
my

```
onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

inside LocationListenerNetwork is never called

If I Use GPS (with ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions) onlocationchanged is called and everything works fine.

This happends only in Galaxy S3 jb (4.1). (correctly setted)
Before update, and on other smartphones, everything works fine:

I Tried on

- Galaxy Nexus 4.2
- Galaxy Nexus 4.1
- Nexus S 4.1
- Galaxy S
- Galaxy Note

Everywhere my code works fine, but in S3 JB I can't understand how to solve.
Another strange thing is that gmaps perfectly tracks position also without gps, so it can't be a device problem.

Comment: Same Problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747543/locationlistener-of-network-provider-is-enabled-but-onlocationchanged-is-never
 if you discover something new, let me know please

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but it might help....

As per this post: [Has NETWORK_PROVIDER behavior changed in Android 4.1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630413/has-network-provider-behavior-changed-in-android-4-1-1)

I and he had similar problem on Galaxy Nexus - and a reboot fixed the problem.